# Boundary value problem in MATLAB, issue with fsolve

Tags: matlab, ode, ode45

I am trying to solve and ODE with boundary conditions at `0` and `end`, ws.mat can be downloaded at https://gofile.io/?c=RYzPsO

```
clear all
clc
global omega eta_max_ode eta F T Tp

eta_max_ode = 10;
omega=0.76;

load('ws','T','Tp','F','eta')
IC=[0,1];

opt = optimset('Display','off','TolFun',1E-20);
FI = fsolve(@(FI) eval_boundary_UVWTI(FI),IC,opt)
[eta_ode_i, fg_ode_i] = solve_UVWTI(FI);

sol_i = [fg_ode_i];
eta_i = eta_ode_i;
plot(eta_i,sol_i(:,1))

function [dfi]=UVWTI(t,fi)
global omega eta_max_ode eta F T Tp

for i=1:length(eta)
    if eta(i)<t
    else
        inde=i;
        break
    end
end

A11=0;
A12=1;

A21=0;
A22=-(T(inde)^(1-omega))*F(inde)-omega*Tp(inde)/T(inde)+Tp(inde)/T(inde);

dfi=zeros(2,1);
dfi(1)=A11*fi(1)+A12*fi(2);
dfi(2)=A21*fi(1)+A22*fi(2);

end

function [eta_ode_i, fg_ode_i] = solve_UVWTI(FI)
global eta_max_ode eta

options = odeset('RelTol',1e-9,'AbsTol',1e-9);

[eta_ode_i, fg_ode_i] = ode45(@UVWTI,eta,FI,options); 
size(fg_ode_i);
end

function [gi] = eval_boundary_UVWTI(FI)
% Get the solution to the ODE with inital condition F
[eta_ode_i, fg_ode_i] = solve_UVWTI(FI);
% Get the function values (for BCs) at the starting/end points

w_start = fg_ode_i(1,1); %w(0) = 0
w_end = fg_ode_i(end,1); %w(inf) = 0

% Evaluate the boundary function
gi = [
     w_start
     w_end - 1
     ];
end
```

I obtained the correct behaviour this is the solution tending to a constant. However, I should get sol_i(:,1) tending to 1 and fsolve does not seem to calculate the correct initial condition so that this happen. What's wrong in the code? eval_boundary_UVWTI() seems to be correct

Comment: What is the termination message of `fsolve`, did it terminate successfully? The target accuracy of `1e-20` seems a little low for computations in numbers with a relative precision of `1e-16`.

Comment: Yes it did terminate successfully. However, even by imposing the condition sol_i(:,1) = 1 at the end of the domain, I don't obtain it